# Printing all paths from a binary tree with python

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree

So I have a pretty dumb question that I can't seem to figure out. I'm just trying to print all paths and how they are being formed from a binary tree using preorder traversal. For that I'm storing each value on a data structure. My question is, why does the behavior change when using *string* vs using a *list* when storing each value on the way?

For a Binary Tree with the following definition:

```py
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, value, left_child=None, right_child=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left_child = left_child
        self.right_child = right_child

left_branch = BinaryTree(5, BinaryTree(3, BinaryTree(7), BinaryTree(10)))
right_branch = BinaryTree(8, None, BinaryTree(4, BinaryTree(6), BinaryTree(9)))
root_tree = BinaryTree(1, left_branch, right_branch)
```

That would look like this:

```
    1
   / \
  5   8
 /     \
 3     4
/ \   / \
7 10 6   9
```

When using a string to store and print the values:

```py
def dfs(root, path):
    if root:
        path += str(root.value)
        print(path)
        dfs(root.left_child, path)
        dfs(root.right_child, path)

dfs(root_tree, '')
```

I get an output:

```
1
15
153
1537  <-- 1st
15310 <-- 2nd
18
184
1846  <-- 3rd
1849  <-- 4rd
```

That's ok.

But when I use a list:

```py
def dfs(root, path):
    if root:
        path.append(root.value)
        print(path)
        dfs(root.left_child, path)
        dfs(root.right_child, path)

dfs(root_tree, [])
```

It doesn't seem to be doing the same thing as it is just storing all nodes on the same path:

```
[1]
[1, 5]
[1, 5, 3]
[1, 5, 3, 7]                 <-- 1st
[1, 5, 3, 7, 10]             <-- ???
[1, 5, 3, 7, 10, 8]
[1, 5, 3, 7, 10, 8, 4]
[1, 5, 3, 7, 10, 8, 4, 6]
[1, 5, 3, 7, 10, 8, 4, 6, 9]
```

I can't seem to understand why this is happening.

Comment: I'm guessing you want a pre-order traversal?

Comment: Yes, but also store each node value on a structure so that I can print the paths of the tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because string is an immutable type, while list is mutable.

Now when you pass the strings in the functions (recursively) whenever it gets modified a new instance of the string is created, cause the original string can't be modified. **Strings are immutable**

However in a list, the modifications done on a list doesn't create a new instance, across the function calls. Python doesn't mind changing the original list, because lists can be modified. **Lists are mutable**.

This behavior of python while handling lists, can be said to be memory optimization, can also be said to be a pure essence of OOP.

To do the same with list just change the code like this:

```
def dfs(root, path):
    if root:
        path.append(root.value)
        print(path)
        dfs(root.left_child, path.copy())
        dfs(root.right_child, path.copy())

dfs(root_tree, [])
```

`copy()` creates a new list object with non-shared memory with original list

However, doing this makes the program consume more memory than it did before.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and the detailed explanation. It helped me a lot.